# find only the files that ended with .whl

Tags: bash, ls, wildcards

I am trying to capture all `.whl` file as the following

```
ls -l  /python/*.{whl,}
ls: cannot access /python/*.: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   23000 Jun 14 11:02 /python/argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  154423 Jun 14 11:02 /python/certifi-2019.9.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  387834 Jun 14 11:02 /python/cffi-1.14.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  133356 Jun 14 11:02 /python/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2728298 Jun 14 11:02 /python/cryptography-2.9.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   11223 Jun 14 11:02 /python/enum34-1.1.10-py2-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   58594 Jun 14 11:02 /python/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   18159 Jun 14 11:02 /python/ipaddress-1.0.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  125774 Jun 14 11:02 /python/Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

but as you can see we get also - `ls: cannot access /python/*.: No such file or directory`

how to fix that , in way to find only the files that ended with .`whl`

Comment: Why `*.{whl,}` instead of the obvious `*.whl`?

Comment: I think you may have wanted `/python/*{.whl,}` or the more obvious ones provided already. Basically the way you gave it, it only found files ending in a `.` or ending in `.whl` ... the whole `{.ext,}` pattern _is_ useful, for example if you have an ISO image and a sha256sum file or a signature, like in `wget https://server/path/to/fle.iso{,.sha1sum,.asc}` ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you’re only interested in files with a `whl` extension,

```
ls -l /python/*.whl
```

is what you’re after.

Your current command,

```
ls -l  /python/*.{whl,}
```

is equivalent to

```
ls -l /python/*.whl /python/*.
```

(thanks to [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)) and fails because the latter pattern doesn’t match anything in `/python`.

Comment: Fair enough. And `{1..4,6..10}` was my bad, should have been `{1..4}{6..10}` ... and I meant the utility for non-contiguous sequences or even for contiguous ones in place of `seq x y` ...

Answer (score 3):

As [@StephenKitt said](/a/594608) said, in `bash`, brace expansion is done before globbing (even before all other other forms of expansions including parameter expansions, see how `bash` is the only shell where `echo $P{S1,ATH}` outputs the contents of both `$PS1` and `$PATH`), so there,

```
ls -l /python/*.{whl,}
```

is the same as:

```
ls -l /python/*.whl /python/*.
```

And `bash` has that misfeature inherited from the Bourne shell that globs that don't match are passed literally to the command, so if there's no non-hidden file in `/python` whose name ends in `.`, the `/python/*.` filename will be passed to `ls` and `ls` complains that that file (yes, `*.` is a perfectly valid file name in Unix) doesn't exist. Note  that the `failglob` and `nullglob` options change that behaviour.

Now, the brace expansion feature comes from csh in the late 70s. And you'll notice that you don't see that error in `csh`.

`csh` doesn't have that misfeature of the Bourne shell and behaves like the `/etc/glob` of early Unices (which gave their name to globs) in that globs that don't match are removed (instead of being passed as-is), and if *all* globs in a command line fail to match, then the command is cancelled (the sensible thing to do as obviously something is wrong).

So in `csh`:

```
ls -l /python/*.{whl,}
```

is first expanded to

```
ls -l /python/*.whl /python/*.
```

like in `bash`, but since `/python/*.` doesn't match any file but `/python/*.whl` matches *some* files, `/python/*.` is removed and `ls` is called with the list of `.whl` files.

If there hadn't been any `.whl` file either, you would have had a `No match` error *by csh*, instead of an error *by `ls`* about non-existing files.

`zsh` is another shell that copied brace expansion from `csh`. The behaviour for unmatched globs is different.

`zsh` doesn't have that misfeature of the Bourne shell (at least not by default) either, but it cancels commands as long as *any* (as opposed to *all* in `csh`/`/etc/glob`) glob fails to match so `ls -l /python/*.{whl,}` or `ls -l /python/*.whl /python/*.` would not run `ls` even though there are `.whl` files, because the `/python/*.` glob doesn't match. In `zsh`, you can get the `csh` behaviour instead with `set -o cshnullglob` or the Bourne behaviour with `set +o nomatch` (not recommended). In `bash`, you can get a behaviour similar to that of `zsh` with `shopt -s failglob`.

The `fish` shell behaviour is yet different.

`fish` (a much newer shell) behaves like `zsh` in that failing globs cancel the command. Like in `zsh`, you'll see that

```
ls -l /python/*.whl /python/*.
```

doesn't run `ls` and returns a:

```
fish: No matches for wildcard “/python/*.”. See `help expand`.
ls -l /python/*.whl /python/*.
                    ^
```

error. But

```
ls -l /python/*.{whl,}
```

does *not* return an error, lists the `.whl` files and does *not* pass a `/python/*.` argument to `ls` behaving in this case like `csh`.

But that's because even though `{x,y}` is not strictly speaking a globbing operator there either, it is done *alongside* globbing, and only if globbing done upon the whole brace doesn't match any file is the command cancelled. You'll see that if there are neither `*.whl` nor `*.` files, the error becomes:

```
fish: No matches for wildcard “/python/*.{whl,}”. See `help expand`.
ls -l /python/*.{whl,}
      ^
```

I.e., the whole `/python/*.{whl,}` is considered *the wildcard* here, not either wildcard resulting from the brace expansion.

To list the files that end in either `.whl` or `.`, I'd do:

```
ls -ld /python/*(.|.whl)  # zsh
ls -ld /python/*.(|whl)   # zsh
ls -ld /python/*@(.|.whl) # ksh / bash -O extglob
ls -ld /python/*.?(whl)   # ksh / bash -O extglob
```

That is, use a *glob operator* within *one* glob that matches either as opposed to two globs, one for each case (unless you want the `.whl` files to be listed first, but in the case of `ls` as the command, that makes no difference as `ls` sorts the list anyway).

Beware however that the `ksh` variants, unless you use `failglob` in `bash` could end-up listing a file literally  called `*.?(whl)` if there was no file matching that pattern because of that Bourne shell misfeature.

in `zsh`, if you wanted to list the `*.whl` files before the `*.` without treating it as an error if either list is empty like in `csh`/`fish`, you could either use `cshnullglob` locally:

```
(){ set -o localoptions -o cshnullglob; ls -ldU /python/*.{whl,}; }
```

(here assuming GNU `ls` and using its `-U` option to disable its sorting).

Or use the `N` glob qualifier (to get a `nullglob` behaviour) and do the error handling (for the case where neither glob matches) by hand:

```
() {
  if (($#)); then
    ls -ldU -- "$@"
  else
    echo>&2 No match
    return 1
  fi
} /python/*.{whl,}
```

Something similar could be done in bash using a subshell (as `bash` doesn't have anonymous functions) for limiting the scope of options and positional parameters:

```
(
  shopt -s nullglob
  shopt -u failglob # failglob takes precedence over nullglob when set!
  set -- /python/*.{whl,}
  if (($#)); then
    ls -ldU -- "$@"
  else
    echo>&2 No match
    exit 1
  fi
)
```